# Как организовать очередь к файлу между сессиями

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Допустим есть файл. В один момент времени им может пользоваться один инстанс программы. Считывать - записывать данные. Программу запускает каждый пользователь под своей учётой windows (через rdp)и при нажатии на кнопку открыть я хочу поставить их в очередь. Как это сделать? Сейчас кто быстрее дождется освобождения файла тот и занимает его

Comment: пропускать файлы через свое приложение. Придумать несколько состояний для файла. И допустим если кто то читает этот файл изменять его состояние на "заблокирован". И после при открытии файла (любым пользователем) считывать его состояние.

Comment: я бы в таком случае отдельный сервис сделал, который пишет в этот файл, а внутри сервиса очередь для клиентов. Вам это вообще для чего? Может и другие варианты найдутся.